# Ruby array.select multiline block

Tags: ruby

I am filtering an array in ruby and using a `.select` block to do so. The conditions are sufficiently complex that a single line block is hideous but not that large so a separate method seems like overkill. Thus I want to use a multiline block. However I am unsure of the syntax.

```
filtered_array = base_array.select do |elem|
    return false if condition1
    return false if condition2
    return true
end
```

The above is clearly incorrect as `return` exits the method, not the block but gives an idea of what I am looking for.

I could also use multiple select statements but that seems to obfuscate what I am trying to do. Note that the above conditions are sufficiently complex that using logical operators to bind them results in a mess.

Comment: You can also use temporary variables.

Comment: Blocks in arrays don't work with return statements (returns would return from the method containing the block) unless they are lambdas, which blocks, by default, are not. The solution to your particular use case is the one that Kyle provided, the general one would be an if or case statement like zetetic provided, and in general, just don't use return statements to return from blocks, unless you know they are going to be lambdas, or turned into methods.

Comment: If you read the question you'll note that I said that `return` "is clearly incorrect" and I want to know what to use instead. Kyle's answer is very messy in the case that I am using. Zetetic's answer is the closest for my use case but doesn't work in the case of compound ifs.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What you want is `next` instead of `return`.

Comment: This works if I want to `return false` but not if I want to `return true`.

Comment: `next` can take a value, just like `return`.  `next(true)` is analogous to `return(true)`.

Answer (score 10):

**Edit:** Just saw this: "using logical operators to bind them results in a mess."
Could you provide the actual conditions?

```
filtered_array = base_array.select do |elem|
    condition1 && condition2
end
```

Comment: I would think that the general concept requires an answer but: `|elem| self.array1.include? elem.name` and the other is a little more complex `elem.name.include? "some string" && self.other_array.include?(elem.name.sub("some string", "other string"))`

Answer (score 6):

You should probably just use:

```
next(true)
```

However if that doesn't jive with you then do this:

```
my_array.select do |x|
  # bool = false ### optional, uncomment this if you prefer
  if x.id == 1
    bool = true
  end
  bool
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this could be handled with a case statement:

```
filtered_array = base_array.select do |elem|
  case
  when condition1
    false
  when condition2
    false
  else
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use next with unless combination till penultimate conditions

```
filtered_array = base_array.select do |elem|
  next unless condition1
  condition2
end
```